# Obj-C - Filter NSMutableArray with another array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an NSMutableArray (self.allPeople) containing a number of dictionaries (people). That said, I also have an NSMutableArray (self.participants) that contains a series of numbers:

**self.participants**

```
Here they are: (
    179,
    125,
    231
)
```

I want filter self.allPeople, and only return dictionaries in which the key "nid" is equal to one of the numbers contained in self.participants.

How can I filter self.allPeople (valueForKey:@"nid") with each number in self.participants?

This works if I only want to filter by a single string value, but I need it to filter for all numbers:

```
  NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nid CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"179"];
  self.results = [self.allPeople filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `IN` for the array, like this:

```
NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *> *allPeople = @[
    @{ @"nid": @120 },
    @{ @"nid": @121 },
    @{ @"nid": @122 },
    @{ @"nid": @123 },
];
NSArray<NSNumber *> *participants = @[ @120, @123 ];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nid IN %@", participants];
NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *> *results = [allPeople filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"RESULTS: %@", results);
```